Video format not supported in Opera snap
I was asked for help with Opera installed on Ubuntu 24.04 via Snap not playing some videos.
I've heard about the issue with ffmpeg version Opera uses, but thought it was about opera installed via APT. It's newest available version installed. It worked previously I also tried to reinstall chromium-ffmpeg snap and reverting opera Update. Nothing worked. I read a lot of posts about copying chromium version of ffmpeg, but these posts are old and if it's snap I cannot directly affected it. I do not know if it was a recent Ubuntu upgrade that make it stop working or the opera update. Have any of you had similar problems with Opera snap?
Can you provide any solution?
EDIT:
I've tried things mentioned by @Rinzwind
Unfortunately it did not help.
I've run the install script it completed but videos still not working.
I've tried to manually download libffmpeg.so and copied it to this places:
/var/snap/opera/
/var/snap/opera/303/
/var/snap/opera/304/
/var/snap/opera/common/

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/

In opera I've checked opera://about and got such install path: 
Install:   /snap/opera/304/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera
And 304 is the newest and 303 is the older one that I also checked.
I tried to copy libffmpeg.so to this install path and got such error:
sudo cp libffmpeg.so /snap/opera/304/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/
cp: cannot create regular file '/snap/opera/304/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/libffmpeg.so': Read-only file system

I got the libffmpeg.so from latest release.
What am I doing wrong?

that advice still is valid. I did it a couple of times with my install fix-opera-linux-ffmpeg-widevine-main.zip  is the download that worked for me.  -> from here https://github.com/Ld-Hagen/fix-opera-linux-ffmpeg-widevine This one works too wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kulfy1/libffmpegOpera/master/libffmpeg.so  :and if it's snap I cannot directly affected it" yes you can... you need to add it to /var/snap/opera/`

@Rinzwind Thanks for help, unfortunately the problem persists. I've edited my question to reflect what have I done and what happened.

that is the wrong dir. install locate and do a locate on libffmpeg.so  It should be something like /var or /lib and then snap/opera/ Sorry I got fed up with having to reapply this everytime opera got uodated and am not using the APT version ... so not sure about the dir.

What is snap connections chromium-ffmpeg? Please check https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/using-chromium-ffmpeg-in-third-party-browser-snaps/6545.

I create a script that install the broken library and fix the opera bug. https://github.com/nicolas-meilan/fix-opera-linux-ffmpeg

I've finally fixed the issue:
The problem was I pasted it into:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/libffmpeg.so
without adding lib_extra directory.
The propper path would be:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/lib_extra/libffmpeg.so
I've found the solution here.
